# Multiple Task Continuation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, continuations

I would like to understand this scenario a little clearer:

Consider the following code:

```
frmProgressAsync prog = new frmProgressAsync(true);
TaskWithProgress t = new TaskWithProgress("Smoothing CP", true);
t.Task = A.ShowMovingAverage(tension,t.Progress)
       .ContinueWith(prev =>
           {
               t.ProgressInformation.Report("Smoothing FG");
               B.ShowMovingAverage(tension, t.Progress);
           });
await prog.RunAsync(t);
```

I have two tasks I wish to run `A.ShowMovingAverage` and `B.ShowMovingAverage`. Both return a Task.

In the `prog.RunAsync()` method, I have the following:

```
    public virtual Task RunAsync(TaskWithProgress task)
    {
        Show();
        TaskIsRunning();
        task.ContinueWith(Close(), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, this._Scheduler);
        return task.Task;
    }
```

So effectively I have three tasks, to run in turn one after the previous is complete.

Now my issue is in some cases the first task completes virtually immediately. When the call to `prog.RunAsync()` is made, and the final continuation is appended to the task, it immediately runs, closing the form.

I can see if I break on the last `ContinueWith()` call, the task status is `RanToCompletion`, but I am kind of expecting the continuation to reset this back to in progress.

Could someone please explain this behavior a little more cleanly? And provide a potential solution so that all the tasks (continuations) complete before the final continuation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tasks only complete one time. When you attach a continuation, you are creating a new task that starts when the antecedent task completes. So, I believe the problem you're seeing is that `RunAsync` is attaching the `Close` continuation but not doing anything with the continuation task; consider `task.Task = task.ContinueWith(Close(), ...)`.

However, I recommend that you use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`. I find that usually clarifies the code and makes it easier to understand.

```
frmProgressAsync prog = new frmProgressAsync(true);
TaskWithProgress t = new TaskWithProgress("Smoothing CP", true);
t.Task = ShowMovingAveragesAsync(A, B, tension, t.Progress);
await prog.RunAsync(t);

private async Task ShowMovingAveragesAsync(TA A, TA B, TT tession, IProgress<string> progress)
{
  progress.Report("Smoothing FG");
  await A.ShowMovingAverageAsync(tension, progress);
  progress.Report("Smoothing FG");
  await B.ShowMovingAverageAsync(tension, progress);
}

public virtual async Task RunAsync(TaskWithProgress task)
{
  Show();
  TaskIsRunning();
  await task;
  Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I notice in both methods, you define the return type as `Task` however you don't actually return anything. Would this not be the same as `async void` which you discourage in your blog?

Comment: No; `async Task` is the proper way to define an `async` method without a return value. It does not have any of the problems that `async void` causes.