# Task Cancelled Exception (ThrowForNonSuccess)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

This is a continuation from this question:
[Multiple Task Continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154692/task-continuiation)

I have changed my code as in the answer, however now I am receiving `TaskCancelledExceptions` when I try to run tasks.

```
public virtual async Task RunAsync(TaskWithProgress task)
{
    Show();
    TaskIsRunning();
    await SetCompletedHandler(TaskComplete());
    await SetCancelledHandler(TaskCancelled())
    await SetFaultedHandler(TaskFaulted());
    await task;
    Close();
}
```

however the following code does not. I am a bit stuck as to why.

```
public virtual Task RunAsync(TaskWithProgress task)
{
    Show();
    TaskIsRunning();
    SetCompletedHandler(TaskComplete());
    SetCancelledHandler(TaskCancelled())
    SetFaultedHandler(TaskFaulted());
    return task;
}
```

The calling code basically involves the following:

```
await progressDialog.RunAsync(task);
```

Edit:

I do not cancel a `cancellationtoken` anywhere so I can't see why this is throwing that exception.

The three SetXXXHandler() methods basically perform the following code with different continuation status:

```
task.ContinueWith(_ => action(), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled, this.Scheduler);
```

The Stack trace is here:

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at FugroDXExt.frmBaseProgressAsync.<RunAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in d:\C#\FugroDXExt\trunk\frmBaseProgressAsync.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at FCP.Forms.frmProcessing.<mnuApplyCenteredSmoothing_ItemClick>d__34.MoveNext() in d:\C#\FCP\FCP\Forms\frmProcessing.cs:line 578
```

`Close()` simply closes the form. If I remove that line the same thing occurs.

Comment: Most likely, some code somewhere is canceling a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Thats the strange thing, its not. I unhooked my `cancellationToken.Cancel()` and it still occurs.

Comment: What is the stack trace? And what does Close() so here?

Comment: what line exactly is throwing the exception?

Comment: The 'await prog.RunAsync' call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say that `SetCancelledHandler` just adds a continuation to the task. I assume that's the same task `RunAsync` gets as a parameter although i can't tell by your code how `SetCancelledHandler` gets a task to continue on (I assume we're  missing some code). Anyways...

You register 3 continuations on a task that will run when the task completes, is canceled and is faulted. Now let's assume the original task ran to completion successfully without being canceled. That means that 2 of your continuations (`OnCanceled` and `OnFaulted`) will not run because they don't need to be. The way to tell a task to not run in the `TPL` is to cancel it, and that happens automatically.

The difference between your 2 code snippets is that in the first one you `await` the task continuations, and they get canceled which explains your exception. On the second snippet you don't await the continuations, just the original task that successfully ran to completion.

P.S: I think the second option is more appropriate. You don't need to `await` all those continuations. You want to let them run if they need to.

TL;DR: You `await` a canceled continuation task. The continuation task, not the original, is the one that throws an exception.