# Xamarin System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler Error while calling a REST service

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, nuget, win-universal-app

I am developing a cross platform Xamarin app on WIndows 10 64-Bit machine. The IDE I am using is Visual Studio 2015.

The problem I get is as below when I run the app from my Windows 10 Emulator/Local Machine.

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at XamarinNativePoc.RESTWSManager.<GetCustomerAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at XamarinWindowsPoc.MainPage.<OnButtonClicked>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

The same is working from Android App. 
The project has a PCL where I have created a REST services manager Class and I have all my REST API calls there. And I am trying to GET details of a customer based on a query parameter (loginName).

I have "Universal Windows" under references and my PCL is also added under the same.

I am not sure how to debug this issue. However, with some research, I have enabled client and server options in Capabilities under Manifest but no luck.

Is this something related to Nuget Packages? Need some help here :)

Comment: That stack trace is very similar to the one posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190552/task-cancelled-exception-throwfornonsuccess see if it helps.

Comment: @Gusman: thanks for this but it didn't help